# How to prove the following set dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis

We consider Banach space $$C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}): \lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=0\}$$ with superum norm.  Is the space $C_b^2\cap C_0(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$?   $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. And how to prove it?

Comment: What is $C_b^2$ space here?

Comment: Start with a function $f \in C_0(\mathbb R)$. By assumption, for each $n$ there is an interval $I_n = [-M_n, M_n]$ such that $|f(x)| < 1/n$ for wvery $x \not\in I_n$. On the compact interval $I_n$ there is a polynomial $p_n$ which is $1/n$-close to $f$. You must find a sufficiently smooth way to extend $p_n$ to all $\mathbb R$ such that the limit in either direction is 0, and then argue that $(p_n)_n$ converges to $f$, which implies the density

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Maybe I understand your idea now.

Comment: In fact, $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ (smooth functions with compact support) is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.  This is a very standard exercise in cutoff functions and Stone-Weierstrass (or convolution).

Comment: Yes, I also want to ask you we get the fact is that $C_c^\infty$ is dense in in $C_0$.

Comment: Because the space $C_c^\infty$ is dense in many Banach space. I have a little bit confused.

Comment: Do you know the reason why $C_c^\infty$ can be dense in many Banach space? e.g. $L^p, W^{k,p}$.

Comment: For $n$ large the convolution with $n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2}$ gives a good smooth (and analytic) approximation of $f$, and since $f$ decays at $\infty$ you can replace $f \ast n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2}$ by $\phi(x/n) \ \  \ f\ast n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2}$ for some $\phi\in C^\infty_c,\phi(0)=1$. It works the same way in every other spaces.