# Why $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ can be dense in different Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

As we know $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}), W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}),C_0(\mathbb{R}), \infty>p\geq 1.$ Why this space can be dense in different Banach space? Is there some deep reason?

Comment: Well the "deep reason" is that amost every reasonable function in almost every reasonable norm has a smooth function near it

Comment: Not true for $p=\infty$

Comment: No, seriously, I can't give you any "deep reason", if you want you can really think about it in the way I said before. For example, mollifying your function works in most cases (in $L^p$ for sure, and I think also in Sobolev spaces), but this is more a technical trick, not a deep reason

Comment: What do you mean "reasonable" function and  "reasonable" norm?

Comment: I also have a stupid question. Is it possible to tell me that the exactly difference between $L^1(a,b]$ and $L^1[a,b]$? I have an example . we consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}$, $f\in L^1(a,b]$ but not in $L^1[a,b]$? is it correct?

Comment: I answered in a comment to your previous question.... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088231/how-to-prove-the-following-set-dense-in-c-0-mathbbr And $1/(x-a) \in L^1_{loc}(a,b]$, as $\int_a^b |1/(x-a)|dx=\infty$ it is not $\in L^1(a,b]$.

Comment: I think I undestand now. Maybe the last $L^1(a,b]$ should be $L^1[a,b].$